# Why mp3url variable is not consoling after clicking the jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I would like to display "mp3Url" variable outside of the jquery click event. Actually is it possible or not from below code snippet? I saw many articles but not working.

```
<script>

var mp3Url;
        
// NOW I CLICK album-poster TO GET CURRENT SONG ID
$(".album-poster").on('click', function(e){

    mp3Url = $(this).attr('data-mp3');

});

//console.log( mp3Url );

const ap = new APlayer({
    container: document.getElementById('aplayer'),
    listFolded: true,
    audio: [
            {
                name: 'Invisible Beauty',
                artist: 'Artist',
                url: mp3Url, // Here is the variable
                cover: 'photo.jpg'
            },
    ]
        
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, before mp3Url did not exist in the context of declaring the APlayer not

```
var ap;
$(".album-poster").on('click', function(e){
    var mp3Url = $(this).attr('data-mp3');
    ap = new APlayer({
        container: document.getElementById('aplayer'),
        listFolded: true,
        audio: [
            {
                name: 'Invisible Beauty',
                artist: 'Artist',
                url: mp3Url, // Here is the variable
                cover: 'photo.jpg'
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Inside of this function console is working but I need outside of the event function.

Comment: it won't have a value until the button is clicked. Why do you need the value outside of the event? you're likely need to do additional code/call a function inside your event.

Comment: Just called a function inside the event but it shows function is not defined when I call it outside of event. May you show an example, please?

Comment: comments aren't for asking more questions, given the original question and code shown this answers the question. if there is more that'd you're trying to accomplish I'd recommend making a new question and posting more code and say what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Please check the question. I've added the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on when you wanna display it. In the current form, you script does three things,

```
1. Declare mp3Url variable (no value assigned)
2. Create and register a function to be execute whenever album poster is clicked.
    a. Assign a value to the variable above (whenever the poster is clicked).
3. Print value of the above variable to console.
```

In step 2 you've just created a function, and 'registered' it to be executed in response to some event in future. When the step 3 executes, `mp3Url` variable will still have `undefined` value, since browser will immediately run steps 1, 2, 3 together without giving the user a chance to click anything. Later whenever user clicks the poster, sub-steps from 2-series will get executed.

If you want the value to be printed 'When user clicks poster', just move the console statement inside the event handler function. This is required, because browser will only run the code written inside the event handler upon user action.

PS: While you're at it you can move the variable inside the event handler too.